# Unity, C# - randomize gap between spawned prefabs but don't allow them to touch?

Tags: c#, random, unity-game-engine

Alright, in my game I have a Runner object that moves at a velocity towards the left towards platforms. I have succeeded in spawning a random platform prefab at a pt a semi-random distance away from the last platform.

I do this by spawning the platform a random distance spacing, which the distance the object has moved since last platform was spawned.

```
public GameObject[] spawnableObjects;
    private GameObject prefab;

    private float spacing; // spawns every 2 units/metres

    public float minY, maxY, minGap, maxGap;
    private float oldX = 0; // previous camera position
    private float newX = 0; // current camera position

    private float distanceTravelled = 0;
    private Vector3 spawnPos;
    public Transform player; // getting camera reference
    public Transform spawnPt;

    private float currentY, lastY, currentX, lastX;

    void Start()
    {
        //set beginning y pos
        GameEventManager.GameStart += GameStart;
        GameEventManager.GameOver += GameOver;
        spacing = 20; //random between length of last prefab and max gap?

        lastY = 0;
        lastX = spawnPt.localPosition.x; //first spawn x pos
    }
    void Update () {
        //Debug.Log (distanceTravelled);
        newX = player.transform.localPosition.x;
        distanceTravelled += newX - oldX; // if you are goint to the right
        // if you're going to the left, do this instead:
        // distanceTravelled += oldX - newX;
        oldX = newX; // this is very important

        if (distanceTravelled >= spacing) {
            distanceTravelled = 0;
            spawnNewObject ();
        }
    }

    void spawnNewObject () {
        // code to spawn. Use the newX + some X offset while declaring your new object's position.
        int rand = Random.Range (0, spawnableObjects.Length);
        prefab = spawnableObjects[rand];

        currentY = lastY + Random.Range(minY, maxY);
        currentX = lastX + (prefab.transform.localScale.x + 5f); //randomize 5, 5 is gap

        spawnPos = new Vector3((spawnPt.localPosition.x), currentY,0f);
        //Debug.Log ("new x:"+currentX);

        Instantiate (prefab, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity);

        lastY = currentY;
        lastX = currentX;
        spacing = Random.Range (prefab.transform.localScale.x+3, prefab.transform.localScale.x+5);
        Debug.Log("spawn now!! spacing="+spacing);
    }
```

The `spawnpt` game object moves at the same acceleration/speed as Runner, so it appears as if platforms are moving towards the Runner.

For some reason, the `Random.Range (prefab.transform.localScale.x+3, prefab.transform.localScale.x+5);` which is the length of the prefab currently being spawned+3 or +4 makes it so the platforms virtually never touch.

My thinking in doing length was if the new platform is being spawned from the empty `spawnPt.localPosition.x`, if the spacing was atleast the length of the current prefab, they wouldn't touch.

Obviously something is flawed in my logic as if I just do `prefab.transform.localScale.x` platforms touch. I need a new approach for this.

How can I have my randomly selected prefab spawn with a randomized GAP between itself and the last prefab that was spawned? I have tried everything including Physics spheres (don't want to go that route) but can't create a gap that I can alter.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The spawn waves does not apply here - does not deal with gap in between platforms or objects

Answer (score 0):

Try overlap sphere (untested):

```
if (!Physics.CheckSphere(spawnPosition, objectRadius)) {
    //instantiate object
}
```

objectRadius is the spherical radius that the object cannot be instantiated within another one

also you can have a Random.insideUnitSphere:

```
spawnPosition = previous.transform.position + Random.insideUnitSphere * spawnRadius;
```

I think that will work.